# Custom mapper for schema validation errors

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, apache-camel

I've used [camel validator](http://camel.apache.org/validation.html) and I'm catching errors from the schema validation like a :

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-minLength-valid: Value '' with length = '0' is not facet-valid with respect to minLength '1' for type
```

Is it any tool which will be good to map this errors for a prettier statements? I can always just iterate on the erros, split on them and prepare custom mapper, but maybe there is sth better than this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created validation with xsd through camel validation component:

```
<to uri="validator:xsd/myValidator.xsd"/>
```

then I've used doCatch inside doTry block to catch exception:

```
<doCatch>
    <exception>org.apache.camel.ValidationException</exception>
    <log message="catch exception ${body}" loggingLevel="ERROR" />
    <process ref="schemaErrorHandler"/>
</doCatch>
```

After that I wrote custom Camel Processor and it works great :)

```
    public class SchemaErrorHandler implements Processor {

    private final String STATUS_CODE = "6103";

    private final String SEVERITY_CODE = "2";

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        Map<String, Object> map = exchange.getProperties();
        String statusDesc = "Unknown exception";
        if (map != null) {
            SchemaValidationException exception = (SchemaValidationException) map.get("CamelExceptionCaught");
            if (exception != null && !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(exception.getErrors())) {
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                for (SAXParseException e : exception.getErrors()) {
                    statusDesc = e.getMessage();
                    buffer.append(statusDesc);
                }
                statusDesc = buffer.toString();
            }
        }
        Fault fault = new Fault(new Message(statusDesc, (ResourceBundle) null));
        fault.setDetail(ErrorUtils.createDetailSection(STATUS_CODE, statusDesc, exchange, SEVERITY_CODE));
        throw fault;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Saxon is really good at error reporting.  Its validator gives you understandable messages in the first place.

Comment: Of course, but what if you need to map this errors to other messages? Unfortunately I've to do this and prepare custom validation errors so I was thinking that maybe exists some tools to do that

Answer (score 1):

That's a SAX error message, and it appears to be quite clearly stated, but see [ErrorHandler](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html) and [DefaultHandler](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) to customize it however you'd prefer.